# How do I autorestart an exited process with exit status 0 in supervisord?

Tags: automation, supervisor

I am executing some PHP script with supervisord. Sometimes one of my processes is stopping with error log:

```
INFO exited: worker_push_notif (exit status 0; expected).
```

I already set in config `autorestart=true` but still, I have to restart it manually. Below is my full config:

```
[program:worker_push_notif]
directory = /opt/initproject/workers
command = /usr/bin/php /opt/initproject/workers/fcm_pushnotif.php
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stdout_logfile  = /var/log/initproject/pushnotif.log
stderr_logfile  = /var/log/initproject/pushnotif.err
```

Need help to handle `autorestart` for exit status `0`. Thank you.

Note: Ubuntu 14.04, Supervisord 3.0

Answer (score 0):

When working out the same problem I created a simple launcher script that returned 1. I called then the launcher script instead of directly calling the original script.
That was enough to trick supervisord. I assume there is a cleaner way, but couldn't find it in the docs.

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/your/script
exit 1
```